# how to change the color of a button in a menu so user knows which page he is in

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

here is the html

```
  <div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
        <a href="#Home" style="width:10%" class="button">home</a>
        <a href="#Hobbies" style="width:10%" class="button">Hobbies</a>
        <a href="#contact_us " style="width:10%" class="button">Contact</a>
        <a href="#services" style="width:10%"class="button">Services</a> 
        <a href="#surprise"><img src="cat.png" id="cat" ></a>
    </div>
```

here is the jquery i thought should work

```
    jQuery("#btn-group .button").click(function(){
        jQuery("#btn-group .button").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

and the css part

```
  .active{
    background-color:#f06f06;;
}
button.btn-group:active{
  background-color:#f06f06;
}
```

Comment: Your jQuery selector is wrong, use  `jQuery(".btn-group .button")`. # is for element with id and you dont have class `btn` but `button`

Comment: @lurker i tried but it still didnt run and i edited above also

Comment: I also didn't look closely enough and see that `btn-group` is a class, not an an `id`. So the correction @Camille mentioned is the proper form.

Comment: When a comment is useful, it's nice practice in StackOverflow community to 'reward' user who made it by clicking on small gray triangle next to comment. Don't mix it with grey flag who is use to flag an inappropriate/offending comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the others said there was no div in the HTML with the ID #btn-group. You changed it to an ID the jQuery code but not in the HTML. I replaced jQuery with $, just because it's easier to use. You can do it like this:

**JS**

```
$("#btn-group .button").click(function(){
        $("#btn-group .button").removeClass('active');
     $(this).toggleClass('active');         
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="btn-group" style="width:100%">
  <a href="#Home" style="width:10%" class="button">home</a>
  <a href="#Hobbies" style="width:10%" class="button">Hobbies</a>
  <a href="#contact_us " style="width:10%" class="button">Contact</a>
  <a href="#services" style="width:10%" class="button">Services</a>
  <a href="#surprise"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .active {
    background-color: #f06f06;
    }
```

Check out this jsfiddle
**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v1wqf6sp/1/)**